# php ооп функция не видит переменную $pdo

Tags: php, ооп

в ооп ни бум бум, пытаюсь понять, почему выдается следующая ошибка:

```
Notice: Undefined variable: pdo in C:\MAMP\htdocs\PolitHouse\model\userinfo.php on line 10

Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function prepare() on null in C:\MAMP\htdocs\PolitHouse\model\userinfo.php:10 Stack trace: #0 C:\MAMP\htdocs\PolitHouse\model\userinfo.php(21): User->userPview() #1 {main} thrown in C:\MAMP\htdocs\PolitHouse\model\userinfo.php on line 10
```

До этого никогда не пользовался ни классами, ни функциями, пытаюсь разобраться как оно работает. Сам код тут:

```
<?php include_once('../controller/db.php');

  class User {


    public $uid = 1;

    public function userPview() {
      $query = ('SELECT politview FROM users WHERE id = :id');
      $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
      $stmt->execute(['id' =>  $uid]);
      $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
      echo $results;
    }

  }


$user = new User();
echo $user->uid;
$user->userPview();
?>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Переменная `$pdo` находится вне своей области видимости

> В программировании, [область видимости](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9E%D0%B1%D0%BB%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C_%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8) (англ. scope) обозначает область программы, в пределах которой идентификатор (имя) некоторой переменной продолжает быть связанным с этой переменной и возвращать её значение. За пределами области видимости тот же самый идентификатор может быть связан с другой переменной, либо быть свободным (не связанным ни с какой из них).

Ознакомится с тем, что такое область видимости и какие они бывают в PHP можно [тут](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.scope.php).

Для решения же вашей проблемы передайте переменную в конструктор класса:

```
<?php

include_once '../controller/db.php';

class User {

  protected $uid = 0,
            $pdo = null;

  public function __construct(int $uid, $pdo) {
    $this->uid = $uid;
    $this->pdo = $pdo;
  }

  public function getId() : int {
    return $this->uid;
  }

  public function userPview() {
    $query = 'SELECT `politview` FROM `users` WHERE `id` = :id';
    $stmt = $pdo->prepare($query);
    $stmt->execute(['id' =>  $this->uid]);
    $results = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
    return $results;
  }

}


$user = new User(1, $pdo);
echo 'User ID: ', $user->getId(), PHP_EOL;
print_r($user->userPview());
```

**Внимание!** Пример кода поддерживается PHP версии 7+